# #1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

Tags: php, xampp, full-text-indexing

Iam trying to execute this query in my xampp, but it is not turning up.

```
SELECT pid,description,alttext FROM wp_ngg_pictures WHERE MATCH 
(description, filename, alttext) AGAINST ('*image2*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND exclude != 1
```

it has returned this error

```
 #1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list.
```

can any one help me plz

Comment: do you have a fulltext index on the `(description,filename,alltext)` tuple? Given the error message, I'm guessing not - you can't just start throwing around fulltext searches without first having created fulltext indexes on the field(s) you'll be doing those fulltext searches on.

Comment: Iam sorry, iam new to this php. i don't know about fulltext. could You plz guide me

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is executing now. i got good info from the link

Answer (score 6):

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD FULLTEXT index_name(column1);
```

Try the above query to add full text index to the columns.

Comment: The key is to have the index matching the columns - it should have exactly as much columns as you are matching.