# unable to use full text search with mysql query using MATCH and AGAINST

Tags: php, mysql

hope someone can help me. I am trying to use the full search text MATCH and AGAINST.

I am getting this error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near `''mytable' WHERE MATCH(user) AGAINST('alex') LIMIT 0, 25'` at line 1

my example query is:

```
SELECT id, user FROM 'mytable' WHERE MATCH(user) AGAINST('alex') LIMIT 0, 25
```

Comment: my database is now MyISAM type but error still persisting

Comment: You don't need quotes around your `'mytable'` tablename instead you can use `backticks` `\`mytable\`` or simply without any `backticks` like as`mytable` if table name is not a special keyword

Comment: what is this error means? #1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to quote mytable. [DOCS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)

```
SELECT id, user FROM mytable WHERE MATCH(user) AGAINST('alex') LIMIT 0, 25
```

For the error mentioned.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD FULLTEXT index_name(user);
```

The fulltext index should contain exactly the same number of columns, in same order as mentioned in MATCH clause.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680472/cant-find-fulltext-index-matching-the-column-list-indexes-is-set) for more.

Comment: what is this error means? #1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

Comment: ALTER TABLE mytable ADD FULLTEXT index_name(user);

Comment: that means you are not using full text index

Comment: @alex use this for more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680472/cant-find-fulltext-index-matching-the-column-list-indexes-is-set

Answer (score 3):

You can only use backticks around table or column name, you can not use anything except backticks.

```
SELECT id, user FROM `mytable` WHERE MATCH(user) AGAINST('alex') LIMIT 0, 25
```

**Where backticks required?**

If your table or column name contains any MYSQL reserve word than you must need to use backtick around the name.

[**MYSQL Reserve Keywords and Words**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)

Comment: what is this error means? #1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

Comment: @alex: r u not using full text index??? u need to add index for full text search. ALTER TABLE table ADD FULLTEXT index_name(column1);

Comment: @alex: or you can also follow this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21693475/1191-cant-find-fulltext-index-matching-the-column-list